# Prestashop products per page

Tags: php, admin, prestashop-1.7

thanks for reading. I want to display all products on the front page (using Prestashop 1.7.1.2) I've followed the normal procedure in the admin back store. **Shop Parameters > Product Settings > Products per page** I set it to 100 after saving, it's however still displaying only 8 products.

Can someone please help me located the .php or .tpl file so I can manually change it? or any other means.

Answer (score 1):

To alter the number of products on the front page, you have to change this in the configuration page of the module named featured products. That's where you can change the number of products displayed on the homepage.